# For schecting, can a blade made of non rusting and non pitting metal, namely tungsten, substitute for steel?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, slaughter-shochet-shecht, metals

To make it easier to schect,could we choose a metal not normally subject to rusting or a need to sharpen? Tungsten is one of the hardest and nonreactive metals that exist.

Comment: Practically speaking, if there was a nick or other flaw in the knife, how would you fix it?

Comment: Tungsten would not nick under that use.